# How to install keras 2.0.5 version in a conda environment

Tags: python, keras, anaconda

I'm using anaconda on a Windows 7 64 bits.

This is what I did:

```
conda update conda
conda create --name my_env python=3.5
conda activate my_env
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.8
```

When I try to install keras 2.0.5:

```
conda install keras=2.0.5
```

I get this message:

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving
> environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible
> so lve. Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving
> environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible
> so lve.
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
> current cha nnels:
>
> - keras=2.0.5
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>
> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package
> you're looking for, navigate to
>
> ```
> https://anaconda.org
> ```
>
> and use the search bar at the top of the page.

I have also tried:

```
conda install -c conda-forge keras=2.0.5
```

With the same above message.

I have checked if keras is already installed:

```
python -c "import keras; print(keras.__version__)"
```

With the message:

> ImportError: No module named 'keras'

I search keras package:

```
conda search keras
```

With the output:

```
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
keras                          2.0.8  py35h15001cb_0  pkgs/main
keras                          2.0.8  py36h65e7a35_0  pkgs/main
keras                          2.1.2          py35_0  pkgs/main
keras                          2.1.2          py36_0  pkgs/main
keras                          2.1.3          py35_0  pkgs/main
keras                          2.1.3          py36_0  pkgs/main
keras                          2.1.4          py35_0  pkgs/main
keras                          2.1.4          py36_0  pkgs/main
keras                          2.1.5          py35_0  pkgs/main
keras                          2.1.5          py36_0  pkgs/main
keras                          2.1.6          py35_0  pkgs/main
keras                          2.1.6          py36_0  pkgs/main
keras                          2.2.0               0  pkgs/main
keras                          2.2.2               0  pkgs/main
keras                          2.2.4               0  pkgs/main
keras                          2.3.1               0  pkgs/main
keras                          2.4.3               0  pkgs/main
```

How can I install keras version 2.0.5. in my environment?

Comment: It seems we never packaged 2.0.5. The easiest would probably be to install it with pip. If you really need a conda package, you could in principle build one in the [`conda-forge/keras-feedstock`](https://github.com/conda-forge/keras-feedstock).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may consider using pip to install and its supported in Conda environment.
Use command:

```
pip install Keras==2.0.5
```

This would not throw any error.